# Is the firestore pricing example for bandwith/network egress calculated correctly?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql, documentation, price

**Issue**

I try to understand the Firestore pricing by recalculating their Firestore pricing example (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/billing-example#see-chats). I am not able to understand their network egress calculation per task.

From my point of view, they split up the network egress bill into 2 tasks.

*1. See lists:* 5 app openings * 10 updated chats * 0.5KB Group document size transit = 25KB Networking

*2. Read messages:* 30 new messages * 0.25KB message document size transit = 7,5KB

*3. Total: 25KB* + 7,5KB = 32,5KB

But in their overview, the documentation says:

Network Egress: (50 * 0.25KB) + (30 * 0.25KB) = 20KB / user / day

**Questions**

Did I understand the calculation correctly? Why is there a difference? What am I doing wrong or is the documentation slightly wrong?

Please provide a calculation example if possible.

**Screenshots:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Since this is a question related to the firestore billing documentation, I consider it would be better that you open a case with the billing team. Have you tried opening a case with them and sharing your calculations? 

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/billing#how_to_contact_support

Comment: I did. But I have not received an amswer